# SwiftUI Protocols as Type: Value cannot conform to `Identifiable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-protocols

Hope you all had a wonderful holidays. Happy new year!

So, I'm using protocols as Type:

```
protocol Protocol_A_Or_B { }
protocol ProtocolA: Protocol_A_Or_B, Identifiable, Hashable, CaseIterable { }
protocol ProtocolB: Protocol_A_Or_B, Identifiable, Hashable, CaseIterable { }
```

I removed all variables and functions from protocols as I consider those are not relevant for the issue I'm facing.

I created a couple of enums that implement either `ProtocolA` or `ProtocolB`. Also, I have a "main enum" that has a method that returns an array of objects that either implements `ProtocolA` or `ProtocolB`, for this, `ProtocolA` and `ProtocolB` have a "parent" protocol (`Protocol_A_Or_B`).

```
enum MainEnum_: Int, Identifiable, Hashable, CaseIterable {
    case One
    case Two
    case Three
    case Four
    case Five
    
    var id:Int { rawValue }
    
    var aOrBEnumArray: [Protocol_A_Or_B] {
        switch self {
        case .One:
            return EnumTypeA.allCases
        case .Two:
            return EnumTypeB.allCases
        default:
            return []
        }
    }
}

enum EnumTypeA: Int, ProtocolA {
    case Option1
    case Option2
    case Option3
    
    var id:Int { rawValue } 
}

enum EnumTypeB: Int, ProtocolB {
    case OptionA
    case OptionB
    case OptionC
    
    var id:Int { rawValue }
}
```

So far, so good. But when I try to send an array of objects that implement `Protocol_A_Or_B`, I get the following errors:

```
Value of protocol type 'Protocol_A_Or_B' cannot conform to 'Hashable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

Value of protocol type 'Protocol_A_Or_B' cannot conform to 'Identifiable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
```

Here's a mock of the `View` where I'm using the objects. I get the errors in the lines of code `TheContentView2(data: arrayEnumTypeA)` and `TheContentView2(data: arrayEnumTypeB)`.

```
struct EnumProtocolsTest: View {
    var arrayEnumTypeA: [Protocol_A_Or_B] = MainEnum_.One.aOrBEnumArray
    var arrayEnumTypeB: [Protocol_A_Or_B] = MainEnum_.Two.aOrBEnumArray
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    TheContentView2(data: MainEnum_.allCases) { item in
                        Text("\(item.name)")
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.purple)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    TheContentView2(data: arrayEnumTypeA) { item in
                        Text("\(item.id)")
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.purple)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    TheContentView2(data: arrayEnumTypeB) { item in
                        Text("\(item.id)")
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.purple)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, for what I understand, I think the error is related with the custom view I have (`TheContentView2`), as it has to receive an array of objects that implements `Identifiable` and `Hashable`.

```
struct TheContentView2<Data: RandomAccessCollection, ElementView: View>: View where Data.Element: Identifiable, Data.Element: Hashable {
    var data: Data
    var itemView: (Data.Element) -> ElementView
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(data) { item in
            itemView(item)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.purple)
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot add my protocols as part of this view's definition/signature, but if it's incorrect then I can request the change.

Hope you can help me. I don't know how I can send an array of objects that implement the parent protocol (`Protocol_A_Or_B`). Not sure what am I missing in the protocol definition or in the custom view's signature.

Thanks!!!

Comment: It seems like `Protocol_A_Or_B` has an `id` property? Is that the only thing common between `ProtocolA` and `ProtocolB`?

Comment: The errors seem clear you didn’t include your protocol code but remove the inheritance to Hashable and Identifiable from Protocol_A_Or_B. You can include the is variable but not the inheritance.

Comment: @Sweeper, as mentioned above: I removed all variables and functions from protocols as I consider those are not relevant for the issue I'm facing. Protocol_A_or_B does have an id property that is implemented in the enums.

Comment: @loremipsum, if I add the inheritance to Identifiable and Hashable to Protocol_A_Or_B as you mentioned, I get more errors: "Protocol_A_Or_B can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements". Give it a try.

Comment: @Aнгел, the error is actually pretty descriptive. `ForEach` (and because of it `TheContentView2`) requires conformance to `Identifiable` and `Protocol_A_Or_B` doesn't conform to it (protocols can only inherit from protocols, they don't *conform* to protocols). So you cannot have an array of `[Protocol_A_Or_B]` used in this way. If you still require different types in the same array, read up on "type erasure"